# Retrieve Java Component name in Mulesoft flow

Tags: java, mule, mule-component

Is there way in Java to get its own Java Component name in the Mulesoft flow?

In other words - how can I get "JavaComponentName" inside its Java code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the method that you are looking for is :

LocationExecutionContextProvider.resolveProcessorRepresentation(String appId, processorPath, element)

According to the java docs:

```
 /**
     * Generates a representation of a flow element to be logged in a standard way.
     * 
     * @param appId
     * @param processorPath
     * @param element
     * @return
     */
    public static String resolveProcessorRepresentation(String appId, String processorPath, Object element)
```

Give it a try and let us know if is working! cheers!